# Addition folders needed to run app in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get my Unity 2d game ready to publish. When I build the project, there are a lot of additional folders needed to run the exe file. Is there a way I could make it to where you only need to download and run the exe file?

Comment: That depends **entirely** on what _platform_ you are targeting.  e.g. _iOS_ may be a single APK file (not that you would notice) but others may be multiple.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're talking about `exe`s I assume you're targeting Windows. You can make an installer using third-party software like Inno Setup. It can pack all files that are needed for your game into one installer file that your players can run to install the game on their machines.
Another option is to just zip the folder and make it downloadable from somewhere. Then users need to unzip the file and run the `exe` inside it.
What you need depends a lot on how you're distributing your game.